# Digital switching system with momentary SPST

Tags: digital-logic, switches

I am a electrical noob. I am trying to build a foot controller for my guitar pedal board. What I want is a digital circuit which has suppose 4 momentary SPSTs and the output of this circuit is 4 bit signal. The circuit should work in the following way: if you press the first button, the output is 0001, press the 2nd, output is 0010, press 3rd, its 0100 and so on.
Please suggest me your ideas or any topics to read.

Comment: Wow, this is a pretty easy one.

Comment: Your explanation leaves a lot to be explained, but personally I would connect the switches to a microcontroller (almost any uC will do), give it to a student, and send him over to you to pick your brain.

Comment: Does the output need to be latched (keep the last value)? Does need to be a default selection? What happens if there's an impossible input? Consider all this to save time and future headaches.

Comment: Thanks you for you answers. As I mentioned before, i am a total noob, I had done a basic electronics course about 6 years back. By the way, I found exactly what i was looking for in this page http://www.geofex.com/article_folders/fxswitchr/fxswitchr.htm (Figure 7).

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all. I found exactly what i was looking for in this page http://geofex.com/article_folders/fxswitchr/fxswitchr.htm (Figure 7).

Comment: It's worth adding a few details of what the page suggests as a solution, otherwise the answer will become useless if the link dies.